# VMware guest eats 100% cpu

Tags: windows-7, vmware-workstation

I have a Windows 7 x64 guest that acts very strange - the VM is very slow and taskmgr will consume 50% (with 2 cores) or up to 99% (single) of the CPU when everything else is idle.

- Host is Windows 7 x64 with VMware Workstation 7.0.1
- VMware tools are installed
- the same VM, when running on another PC with VMware Server 2.0 will work OK (CPU at ~0% when idle)

I've tried (with no effects)

- enabled/disabled 3d
- selected 1 or 2 cores
- adjusted memory (1gb/500mb)
- adjusted the bios
- mem.hotadd = "FALSE"
- disabled page trimming

Windows 7 x86 guests on the same machine do not have this problem.

---

Edit: I usually run multiple VMs on that system.

Now I noticed that

- if I start the x64 VM first it will run OK.
- but when I start another VM (x86) with multiple processors it will have CPU issues.
- if I suspend the first VM the issues in the second VM will disappear.

Apparently I can only run one VM with multiple processors without issues.

Comment: What CPU does the host have?

Comment: It has a Intel Core2 Duo T9300 (2.5GHz). VMware let's me select 2 processors and 2 cores.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updating to Workstation 7.1 resolved the issue.

Comment: Thank you for informing us of the solution to the problem. However, best practice is for the poster to update only his post, leaving the answers area to others.

Comment: @harrymc - you must be new here. From the FAQ: "It's also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question"

Answer (score 1):

My only thought is to check to make sure VT-x is enabled in bios and being utilized by vmware workstation though I am thinking the x64 images won't boot without it.....worth double checking though.

Comment: Yes, VMM is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try removing Aero from the host? That caused me a headache sometime ago (and the guest also).

Other thing: Select only 1 CPU since you have only one. Add 2 cores if you want, since you've got two. It's simply because you give out too much CPUs. Try only giving out 1 or 2 cores. (Or play with this setup).